# Unity - issue with AudioClip array

Tags: unity-game-engine, audioclip

I'm trying to make an audio player in Unity.
I first created a ResourceManager, that has a
`AudioClip[]` array.

```
public class ResourceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSrc;
    public AudioClip[] clips;
    private int trackNum = 0;
    
    public void Awake()
    {
        audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSrc.Stop();

    ...omitted...
        
    public void LoadClip()
    {
        audioSrc.clip = clips[trackNum];

    }
}
```

So that they appear in the `Clips` drag-and-drop box.

[image]

However, I want to make the AudioClip array static in `ResourceManager` static, so other scripts (e.g. `PlayPause.cs` can access `clips` statically (via function calls).
But the problem is once I make `clips` static, the drag-and-drop for  disappears.

Is there a way to fix that? Or are there some better design patterns? Thanks.

Comment: Make the MonoBehaviour a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. simply do

```c#
public class ResourceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    // This is the one in the Inspector
    // Usually I keep the Inspector private and only provide public access 
    // where needed via properties 
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] clips;

    // This will be set in Awake to the ones from the Inspector
    // readonly for others, only this class can assign it
    public static AudioClip[] Clips { get; private set; }
    
    public void Awake()
    {
        Clips = clips;

        ...
    }
}
```

---

The alternative suggested is make the `ResourceManager` a so called *singleton* like e.g.

```c#
public class ResourceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you store your own instance reference  
    // and provide public readonly access
    public static ResourceManager Instance { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] clips;

    public AudioClip[] Clips => clips;

    ...
    
    public void Awake()
    {
        // Make sure only one instance exists at a time
        if(Instance && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;

        // optional: Don't destroy this instance when the scene is switched
        // Careful: Make sure this applies also to the AudioSource instance!
        // For now I assume it is either attached to this object or a child
        // if not simply do the same DontDestroyOnLoad on it as well
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);         

        ...
    }
        
    public void LoadClip()
    {
        audioSrc.clip = clips[trackNum];
    }
}
```

And then access everywhere `ReaourcesManager.Instance.Clips`

---

Or a built-in alternative to the *singleton* is using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) so any other script in the Scene can actually simply access

```c#
FindObjectOfType<ResourcesManager>().clips
```

**without you having to change anything at all ;)**

Except as said I would make it

```c#
[SerializeField] private AudioClip[] clips;

public IReadonlyList<AudioClip> Clips => clips;
```

depending a bit of course what exactly you want to do with the clips but this way the array can not be altered by any other script

Comment: What does [SerializeField] do? Sorry I'm new to C# (:

Comment: [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) is Unity specific attribute and allows to serialize (show in the Inspector and save in the assets) a `private` field ;)

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer! Thanks. But if I make changes to one of the arrays, say `Clip` (As I'd want to delete from it), can the changes be reflected to `clip` as well?

Comment: It is the very same array reference -> any change will affect "both" ... except for the very last example where I used an `IReadonlyList` instead .. there nobody else can change anything in the returned read only collection